# Why are aircraft coloured in yellow during construction, repair or overhaul?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-maintenance, paint

[image: sukhoi 30 on production line]
Why are aircraft usually coated with "yellow", while either during construction or repair and overhaul?
What exactly is the purpose of it?

Comment: Could you please provide the source of your image?

Comment: What type of plane is that?

Comment: The aircraft in the picture is Su-34

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For unassembled and new planes or planes not yet painted the [green/yellow color you see is the anti-corrosive coating on the aluminum](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/en/blogs/2017/april/the-history-of-the-green-aircraft)

> ...every unpainted airplane is nominally green from being coated
>   (typically) with an anti-corrosive green zinc chromate or zinc
>   phosphate primer over the aluminum skins. The different shades of
>   green simply tell you that different vendors produced the different
>   pieces—they don’t all use the exact same primer.

Originally it was some variation on [Zinc Chromate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_chromate) but it was found to be fairly toxic other things have been used over time which lead to the more [green color](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/1184ZincChromatePrimer.pdf) and even some potentially ["chrome-free"](https://www.duncanaviation.aero/debrief/2010/Fall/the-rise-of-chrome-free-paint-why-aircraft-paint-systems-are-going-green) options.

Comment: do you mean nominally or normally?

Comment: @bogl: It's a quote from the given link. "Nominally" is in the original.

Comment: To add to this, in the US, you will typically see the trade name "Alodine", which is usually called out in drawings as something along the lines of "CHEM. CONVERSION COAT PER MIL-DTL-5541 <or MIL-C-5541>, TYPE <X>, CLASS <Y>", where <X> is I for coatings with hexavalent chromium or II for coatings with no hexavalent chromium, and where <Y> is 1A for maximum corrosion protection, painted or unpainted, or 3 where the corrosion protection needs to preserve electrical conductivity.

Comment: "nominally" would be the normal, expected word here, FWIW.

Comment: Lamp black is added to yellow zinc-chromate to make it resistant to UV light and increase wear resistance. This results in a green color. The more lamp black that is added, the greener the color.